# How to fix background image?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am using a background image and repeating it. When it hits the second row, it seems to lose opacity.  Funky!  I have never seen this kind of behavior before. I have made lots of little tweaks but nothing seems to fix it.

What would cause this? How can I fix it?

You can see it here:  http://movies.evikjames.com/

(If you are reading this an hour after this post, don't expect to see the issue.)

Comment: It's just optical effect I guess, Because the bottom of the image is darker, the top of the repeating line seems to very light. There is nothing in the css that would cause this effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an optical illusion. Take a screenshot of the page, open it in an image editing program, select the top of one of the images in the bottom row, and drag it up towards the top of the image. You will see that the top row is indeed the same color/opacity as the bottom row.

I believe the section of the Wikipedia article on optical illusions titled ["Colour and brightness constancies"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_illusion#Colour_and_brightness_constancies) has information on similar illusions.

Comment: Wow! I have never been so utterly fooled in my life.  Thanks!

Comment: Same idea, same time of response :)

Answer (score 3):

Use color picker. Is just an optical illusion :) when different shades of grey meet nearby.

Comment: Yeah, using the color picker would have been a great idea. Of course, I think I probably would have thought that it was just broken.